Query only AWS S3 bucket prefixes from snowflake
Query only AWS S3 bucket prefixes from snowflake. From the example below, I only want to get a list of "test1, test2, test3".
Example:
S3://Bucket1/test1/file1.csv
S3://Bucket1/test2/file1.csv
S3://Bucket1/test3/file1.csv

I tried using "ls" command but due to huge amount of files I am getting the error message listed below.
Error:
Total size (>=1,073,742,040 bytes) for the list of file descriptors returned from the stage exceeded limit (1,073,741,824 bytes); Number of file descriptors returned is >=4,329,605. Please use a prefix in the stage location or pattern option to reduce the number of files.

Is there any other elegant way to list the prefixes only? The other option I am thinking of using is directory tables.

honestly if you have more than 4m files in a bucket, you will need to have applied a known structure to them. To improve your file loading experence. For it to even be viable. like we we put our data into S3 we had the roots be message sources. Thus given we data engineers we knew what our sources where, we could access these as known seperate things. Then add some for of time based heiarchy is critical, yyyy/mm/dd/hh is a good start depends on your file creatation rates. After this you can use load patterns like type1/2024/11 to load all file in Nov 24

This is all part of the working with S3 working best pratices documentation since 2016. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-manage

I used prefixes and patterns while loading the data using copy command. This is not an issue while loading data. However, what I am looking for is to get a list of all prefixes test1, test2, test3 from my example.

Snowflake is design to load files, as you have done. What it's not designed to do is, "think about the meaning of the names of those files". AWS S3 Console however is designed to make meaning of large sets of files, and will show you the root file/paths (albeit there is no path) but use the console.

Thank you for your response, I am deciding to go with a control file approach to keep track of all existing and new S3 prefixes.

You could try the following as a means to filter the results based on some prefix / identifier for listing :
select t.$1, t.$2 from @mystage1 (file_format => 'myformat', pattern=>'.*data.*[.]csv.gz') t;

this is more of a regex pattern matching means to be able to get the file listing but based on my understanding of the question posted, it would require some more object naming convention to make it even more optimized.

I used prefixes and patterns while loading the data using copy command. This is not an issue while loading data. However, what I am looking for is to get a list of all prefixes test1, test2, test3 from my example. –
